# Listen for a specific key using pynput keylogger?

Tags: python, pynput

I'd like to create a key logger that would listen for the keys 'w' 'a' 's' 'd' and whenever it detects these keys, adds them to a list. So far I have this code

```
from pynput.keyboard import *
keys_pressed=[]
def on_press(key):
        print(key)

def on_release(key):
    if key==Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

How could I check if a specific key is pressed, and add it to the keys_pressed list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`KeyCode.from_char(char)`](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.KeyCode.from_char) to get the key from the specified char. So `KeyCode.from_char('w')` would return the key for `w`.

Then you can store your keys corresponding to W, A, S and D in a list or whatever and check in your callback if the pressed key equals to one of these.

Here is an example:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import *

keys = [KeyCode.from_char(c) for c in 'wasd']

def on_press(key):
    if key in keys:
        print(f'good key: {key}')
    else:
        print(f'bad key: {key}')

def on_release(key):
    if key==Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you! I used this code and it worked fine: https://prnt.sc/u6h0ai
However I get another error when I press a special key like spacebar, how would I fix that? The error is: https://prnt.sc/u6h0j0

Comment: It's because when the key pressed is not a letter, it's a `Key` object and not a `KeyCode` and only `KeyCode` object has `char` field. With my solution it should work fine, or before checking the char you can check if it's a `KeyCode` and not a `Key`

Comment: How could I iterate over the list? It gives me this error: TypeError: 'KeyCode' object is not iterable. I know I can turn it into a string, but is there any other way, other than turning into a string?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, can you please provide your code ?